# How to make particular node in xml to appear in A3 size through xsl..rest in A4

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

We are converting an XML to PDF output in R4i tool by styling it with xsl.
The PDF document should be entirely in A4 size except the figure node(should be in A3 size).
Whenever XML contains figure node it should be on new A3 page. While rest of the XML document will continue to be on A4. figure tag might be at any level. How we can achieve this using xsl.
   Sample XML:-

```
   <content>
      <refs>
         <dmRef>
            <dmRefIdent/>
         </dmRef>
      </refs>
      <description>
         <description>
            **<figure id="fig-0003">
               <title>XXXX</title>
                  <graphic id="fig-0003-gra-0001" infoEntityIdent="b.png"/>
                  <graphic id="fig-0003-gra-0002" infoEntityIdent="b.png" />
            </figure>**
         </description>
         <levelledPara id="par-0001">
            <figure id="fig-0002">
               <title>XXXX</title>
                  <graphic id="fig-0003-gra-0001" infoEntityIdent="a.png"/>
                  <graphic id="fig-0003-gra-0002" infoEntityIdent="a.png" />
            </figure>           
         </levelledPara>
         <levelledPara id="par-0002">
         </levelledPara>
         <levelledPara id="par-0003">
            <para>
               <internalRef internalRefId="fig-0003" internalRefTargetType="ir01"/> XXXX </para>
            </levelledPara>
            **<figure id="fig-0003">
               <title>XXXX</title>
                  <graphic id="fig-0003-gra-0001" infoEntityIdent="b.png"/>
                  <graphic id="fig-0003-gra-0002" infoEntityIdent="b.png" />
            </figure>**
      </description>
   </content>
```

Answer (score 1):

R4i uses XSL-FO, so you need to edit the XSL-FO stylesheet.

This .xslt file contains statements like this for the page size:

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="cover" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin="0mm">

<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="index">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page_odd" page-position="any" blank-or-not-blank="not-blank"/>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page_blank" page-position="any" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
</fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```

You need to create new simple-page-masters and a new page-sequence-master for A3. Then the `figure` node must be linked to the new masters:

In the part of the template that processes the `figure` node, there is an instruction that links a page sequence master:

```
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A3">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How we can link A3 master referance to all the figure node irrespective of there position and level? we have a page break at figure template. and normal page break is at content node.

Comment: @AnkurMukherjee It will be difficult to generate A3 fo:page-sequence that is independent form A4 fo:page-sequence. If you create a stylehseet in the normal manner, the two A3 fo:page-sequence will be nested under the A4 fo:page-sequence. In that case it is useful to use [PSMI](https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/resources/psmi/index.htm) technique. I always use this stylesheet for post-presessing of XSL-FO.

Comment: I don't know which XSLFO processor is used by R4i. If it uses the current version of Antennahouse Formatter, you can nest page sequences without PSMI.

Comment: @Hobbes Can we get some guidance on this?

Comment: @AnkurMukherjee [Nested <fo:page-sequence>](http://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v64e/ahf-ext.html#fo.page-sequence) will work as long as you us AH Formatter. PSMI is general solution.